# pyuic5 works on one machine but not another

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, pyuic

Pyuic5 is working just fine on one computer, but not on another (both OsX). When I try to run pyuic5 to convert a .ui file to a .py file, I get this;

```
$ pyuic5 -x evaluate.ui -o ui_Evaluate.py
-bash: pyuic5 -x: command not found
```

However, if I type plain-old “pyuic5” at the command line, I get this:

```
$ pyuic5
Error: one input ui-file must be specified
```

If I follow those directions and specify an input ui-file, I get this:

```
$ pyuic5 evaluate.ui
-bash: pyuic5 evaluate.ui: command not found
```

And, when I type “pyuic5 -h” in the command line, I get this:

```
$ pyuic5 -h
Usage: pyuic5 [options] <ui-file>

Options:
  --version             show program's version number and exit
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
…
```

So clearly I can run pyuic5 from the terminal, but once I try to pass it an argument other than “-h”, it gives me a “command not found” error.

I checked the location of pyuic5 on both computers, and on both computers it is using the Anaconda version stored in the “opt” directory.  The only difference between the two machines is that one is a 2018 Intel iMac, and the other is a 2021 Apple silicon MacBook Pro.  I'm scratching my head as it works just fine on my iMac, but not on my MacBook Pro.  I'm teaching how to use QT with Python this week, and I kinda need it to work on my MacBook so I can demonstrate it in class.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.  I get: `.../opt/anaconda3/bin/python: No module named pyuic5`

Comment: Ooops  try with: `python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic evaluate.ui -o ui_Evaluate.py -x`

Comment: [posted before I saw your reply] I hunted down pyuic5, and it turns out it is just a batch file that calls “PyQt5.uic.pyuic“.  On a hunch, I tried the following, and it works! `python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic evaluate.ui -o ui_Evaluate.py -x`